# Triggering keyboard event with JS which pynput recognizes

Tags: javascript, python, keyboard, listener, pynput

I am running a website in Python's Bottle framework and I am using the keyboard listener from pynput package. The listener is stopped when delete key is pressed. I want the listener to stop, when a certain button in HTML file is clicked on as well. I want to write a function in JavaScript which will be executed when the button is clicked on and which will trigger the delete key to be pressed (which will consequently make the listener stop).

I have found many JS functions on the internet which trigger the delete button to be pressed, but in none of those examples did the keyboard listener stop. The listener in Python never recognized those events. Does anyone know a way to write such JS function that will trigger a key to be pressed and that the listener in Python will recognize that the key has been pressed?

EDIT:

Here is a part of my code (the pynput part):

```py
def on_press(key):
    try:
        k = key.char
    except:
        k = key.name
    print('Key pressed: ' + k)
    if k in ['left', 'right', 'up', 'down', 'delete']:
        #print('Key pressed: ' + k)
        return False  

def dobi_smer():
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press)
    listener.start()
    listener.join()
    with keyboard.Events() as events:
        for event in events:
            if event.key == keyboard.Key.left:
                return 'L'
            elif event.key == keyboard.Key.right:
                return 'R'    
            elif event.key == keyboard.Key.up:
                return 'U'        
            elif event.key == keyboard.Key.down:
                return 'D'
            elif event.key == keyboard.Key.delete:
                return 'X'
```

It listens to the keyboard until one of the arrows or delete key is pressed.

According to the answer, I have created also created a new page in my website which would simulate the delete key being pressed. Here is the code in Bottle:

```py
@bottle.post("/igraj/prekini/")
def igraj_prekini():
    print("bla")
    keyboard.press(keyboard.Key.delete)
    keyboard.release(keyboard.Key.delete)
```

I have tried to send this post request with AJAX with the following functions:

```js
function prekini() {$.post("/igraj/prekini/")}
```

and

```js
function prekini() {$.ajax('/igraj/prekini/', {type: 'POST'})}
```

but neither of these two functions worked as the page /igraj/prekini/ was never reached. (string "bla" was never printed)

Comment: Reading some docs, it sounds like pynput listens at the hardware layer, where JS can only simulate a keydown event in the DOM. Generally, for security reasons, the JS on a website can't interact with input devices or the OS directly. I think you'd be better off looking at a different approach.

Comment: Are you trying to listen `stop` button click using javascript and want to stop listening form `pynput`? Stop button in html --> clicked --> stop listening from pynput

Comment: @Kshitiz Yes, I want to create a button in HTML which would stop pynput from listening once it has been clicked. If there is some other way to create such a button without JavaScript, I would be happy to hear that way as well.

Comment: I will try answer your question with useful details, probably I am not going to write code for you in `bottle`, but I can give you some idea will details. Is it okay for you? I can give you some advice, because I am a `flask` guy. If you want code then I can probably provide you code after reading documentation and all those stuff. What do you want?

Comment: @Kshitiz Thank you very much! I think that the idea with the details will be enough. If I won't know how to implement some part of your explanation, I can ask you later about the specific problem. But I promise I will first try very hard to implement it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stop `button` in html, and a write javascript function to listen `click` in that button. Now, your function works when you `clicked` that `button`. So, in that function you can write AJAX code to call some url like `/stop_pynput` and a `/stop_pynput` route in `bottle` like your home page `/`. And write code that stops `pynput` there or call some functions there and return something. So, Now you have to gain skill to solve this problem with my idea, if you already know it then that's best but if you aren't familiar with ajax then try asking it in comment.

Steps to do in list form:

1. Stop button in HTML
2. Listen click using js
3. Ajax request to some internal url
4. In bottle make that route
5. Now, main part. Inside that route/function or inside that route write run script to stop your pynput

If any queries, then feel free to ask in comment.

Comment: I understand every step of your explanation completely. I don't know any Ajax but I will immediately try to find on the internet how to request for internal url. I know how to do everything else. Thank you very very much again!

Comment: These links may help you https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp   https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ yeah! You can do your own research and you try to do that

Comment: Oh! I found that bottle is preety easy after checking documentation and some other stuffs, If you want code then feel free to tell me. I can help you with that also now! But I recommend you to try on your own first as you already told I will try my best :)

Comment: So this is what I did: first I set the the HTML onclick property of the stop button to function prekini().  I defined function prekini() like this: `function prekini() {$.post("/igraj/prekini/")}`. And when I send a post request to /igraj/prekini/ the following code is executed: `keyboard.press(keyboard.Key.delete)` and then `keyboard.release(keyboard.Key.delete)`. But this doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have just figured out that the function that should be executed when a post request is sent to /igraj/prekini/ is never executed (when I try to print something inside of that function, nothing is printed when I press the button).

Comment: Is there any progress or, you are stuck there?

Comment: I have tried to define `prekini()` like this as well: `function prekini() {$.ajax('/igraj/prekini/', {type: 'POST'})}` but it didn't work either. I continued searching through the internet for some time but I couldn't find the solution. I have never used AJAX before so I don't understand it and that's why I probably missed the correct solution when looking on the internet.

Comment: Can you please share you `punput` code, I am little bit confused to you are while doing pynput code? I have completed `bottle` and `ajax` part but doing `pynput` is confusing!

Comment: Just edit your question, as here is my effort and code.

Comment: I have edited the question and the pynput code in there now.

Comment: If your problem is with ajax only then here's code `<button onclick="test()">Stop</button>` `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
```<script>function test() {$.ajax({url: "/igraj/prekini",success: function(result){alert(result);}});}</script>
```

Comment: You don't have to send a POST requests but if you want to send this in post requests then `$.ajax({url: "/igraj/prekini",type:"POST",success: function(result){alert(result);}});` will be enough in js but you know how to handle, `get` and `post` method in bottle RIGHT?

Comment: It doesn't work... I'm not getting any alert and the listener doesn't stop when the stop button is pressed. I have tried now adding an invisible button which triggers the post request when pressed. I have added a function which simulates a click on the invisible button when the stop button is pressed. The function which presses the invisible button is executed successfuly, but the post method is never executed. Do you maybe understand why this happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234698/discussion-between-kshitiz-and-hinko-pih-pih).